# Is a used copy of the first Call of Duty playable?

Tags: call-of-duty

Does the first Call of Duty for PC have any copyright protection that makes a used, complete copy bought from Amazon unplayable?

The reason why I think there might be an issue: Even with a complete copy, if the game 'calls in' to a server on installation and asks if this specific copy had been installed before, there may be a problem. CoD predates Steam but there may be a similar system in use.

Comment: If it's a legit copy, there should be no restrictions

Comment: I doubt it.  It either runs off the disk, or installs via the disk and needs the disk to run.

Comment: Damn, ninja'd when trying to edit it.

Comment: Agreed. Just because you got a down vote doesn't mean you should attack them. Besides, they'd have more rep points.

Comment: Ok, wow, was not meant to attack anyone - just explain the reason why I think I might have an issue at all! I see the problem with my wording though.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching, *cannot find any evidence* that suggest that Call of Duty (2003) uses any kind of DRM that needs to check back to a "home" server and confirm the CD key. * (*Note 1*)

Based on it's [Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/2620/), the original Call of Duty does use 3rd-party software (Punkbuster) for anti-cheat, but I do not see anything else in it's store page that would be used to check-in the CD-Key. (Much like uPlay for example.)

With all that said, you should be ok to re-use a CD key if you're installing straight from the retail disc.  Even if the key has been "used up" already (as in tied to a Steam account), the original retail version does not seem to make any internet requests during installation to check the key. It only checks it locally to make sure it's authentic.

---

*Note 1*: As user598527 points out, Call of Duty (2003) does use [SafeDisc DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SafeDisc) to  authenticate of the installation media. This software will try to block the instillation of the game if certain hidden values don't check out compared to the original retail copies at the time of pressing. It's main purpose was to prevent people from burning a copy of the original install CD, and using that copy by the way of encrypting/decryption of parts needed to install and run the software. As long as the disc itself is the original, SafeDisc shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Safedisc DRM: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty#Availability